# How to remove stopwords using stanford nlp

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp, stop-words

I want to parse the document using stanford nlp and remove stopwords from that, so my question is how to remove stopwords using stanford nlp is there any api to remove that, I find StopWords class but I dont know how to use this, please suggest me how to get this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show some effort.  What have you tried to do with the StopWords class that isn't working?

Comment: i have just parsed some text using stanford nlp, i dint tried any stopwords class, i am just asking for your suggestions how to remove stop words

Comment: The first step in addressing this question for anyone performing this function is what stopwords list do you wish to use?  The answer likely varies for the task/corpus you are working with

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use this annotator to remove stop words  https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp

Comment: +1 No think about it, this is the recommended approach on Stanford's CoreNLP [page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)

Comment: Does NOT explain Stanford NLP

Comment: @demongolem That link just directs to their About page, which doesn't mention stop words. Do you have a link to a specific article they have on removing stopwords with CoreNLP? I've searched all the questions their help account has answered looking for stopword questions, they are few.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct the annotator mentioned by @Raju Penumatsa above is accessible on Maven here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zensols/stopword-annotator And maintained in another git repo here: https://github.com/plandes/stopword-annotator

With the usage of the Maven repository you can easily use the annotator in your project as a dependency by importing it with a build tool such as Maven or Gradle etc. and you don't have to copy the lib into your classpath manually, so it is easier and more maintainable. The Git repo I linked moved the stopword plugin of the jconwell/coreNlp project into a separate repo and added some additional metadata in order to be able to publish it on Maven Central.

Comment: links as answer is acceptable, but please consider to put some information what it does, why this solves the problem.  Please consider to check [answer]

Comment: I thought it is somehow self explanatory. With the usage of the Maven repository you can easily use the annotator in your project as a dependency by importing it with a build tool such as Maven or Gradle etc. and you don't have to copy the lib into your classpath manually, so it is easier and  more maintainable. The Git repo I linked moved the stopword plugin of the jconwell/coreNlp project into a separate repo and added some additional metadata in order to be able to publish it on Maven Central. :)